# Thresholding for Pupil (Eye Tracking) - OpenCV with C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, eye-tracking

I have just started to work on pupil tracking. I have did some thresholding for the pupil but still not as accurate as needed. Below is my current thresholded image

Current Thresholded image

[image: img]

I would preferably like to see only the pupil in the contour but unfortunately I see other noises as well. Below is my code

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{ 
     Mat src, src_gray, src_bw_glint, src_bw_iris, dst, dsti;
     int threshold_value1 = 130;
     int threshold_value2 = 30;
     int const max_BINARY_value = 255;
     VideoCapture cap(1); // open the default camera
     if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
         return -1;
     Mat frame;
     vector<vector<Point> > contours;
     vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

     int p = 0;

     for(;;)
     {

        cap >> src; // get a new frame from camera

        /// Convert it to gray
        cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

        Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( src_gray.size(), CV_8UC3 );

        /// Reduce the noise so we avoid false circle detection
        GaussianBlur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );
        namedWindow( " Demo_Gray", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        imshow( " Demo_Gray", src_gray );

        //Threshold
        threshold( src_gray, src_bw_iris, threshold_value2, max_BINARY_value, 1);

        int morph_size = 5;
        Mat element = getStructuringElement( MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size( 2*morph_size + 1, 2*morph_size+1 ), Point( morph_size,morph_size ) );
        cout<<element;

        morphologyEx( src_bw_iris, dst, MORPH_DILATE, element,Point(-1,-1), 1);
        //imshow("Open Image", dst);
        morphologyEx( dst, dsti, MORPH_TOPHAT, element,Point(-1,-1), 10 );
        //imshow("TopHAt Image", dsti);
        morphologyEx( dsti, dsti, MORPH_DILATE, element,Point(-1,-1), 1);
        imshow("TopHAt Image", dsti);

        findContours( dsti, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

        for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
        {             
            //Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255));
            Scalar color = Scalar(p, 255, p);

            drawContours( drawing, contours,i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
            // circle( drawing, mc[i], 4, color1, -1, 8, 0 );                
            imshow("Drawing", drawing);                
        }

        if (waitKey(1) == 'q') {
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0; 
}
```

I like to know the best thresholding approach for my work in order to track only the pupil. Also, Please let me know, if you think, this could be made much simpler than what I have did.

Comment: try to find out properties of each object and leave only those that are most similar to disc (for example `set_pixel_area/bounding_box_area` ratio should be close to `PI/4` )

Comment: decrease your threshold. the pupil is much darker than 130.
alternatively: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3260/30b941d44ffe6ec33f1b20b5897c4f198f7b.pdf

Comment: decrease your threshold, try using _HoughCircles_

Comment: An [article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/137623/pupil-or-eyeball-detection-and-extraction-by-c-fro) on CodeProject explains in detail a similar project written in C#. Their algorithmic approach can be written easily enough with OpenCV. Essentially, invert colors of your image, grayscale the result, use a binary filter with a more aggressive threshold (like 220). At this point, you've practically isolated the pupil and you just identify the largest blob in the remaining scene. Locate that blob and then crop it out of the original photo and you've got your colored pupil!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that work a the thresholding is going to improve your result.

Here is what I would do:

1. On your binary result, apply an opening with a big circular structuring element. All the small patterns will be erased, only the big (more or less) circular will remain.
2. Extract shape indexes, mainly circularity indexes (see [a list here](http://www.thibault.biz/Doc/Publications/ShapeAndTextureIndexesIJPRAI2013.pdf)).
3. The more circular pattern will be the pupil.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend pre-processing with a median filter

Your image without any filter:

[image: your image]

and your image processed with a median filter:

[image: your image processed with a median filter]